# Same module name across multiple files

Tags: import, module, d

I don't know if it is even possible: I want to span a module across multiple source files so that I dont have to put every class in a module to one file. 
So I have two files named "FileA.d" , "FileB.d" , and I want them both to start with a module name:
"module amodule"

The problem is later, when I want to import it, I dont know even how.

doing "import FileA" yields an error:

```
 "module amodule from file FileA.d must be imported as module 'amodule' "
```

I cant really figure out what this means as the documentation doesnt mention anything about this.
So my question is - is it possible and , if yes - how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Bad idea - there is a reason why you want multiple classes per module. Try not to think the C++/Java way. This solves the C++ friend hell...

Answer (score 2):

a better way would be to create a module `amodule` and have that `public import FileA, FileB;`

Comment: I want to the classess in the module to be friends. So this probably doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: the files can import each other

Comment: right, but you can use the package protection level to get around this. call them foo.filea, foo.fileb, and then they can see each other's things marked package instead of private. it is the next best thing.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is not easy for a good reason. Module level access solves C++ friend hell. If you come from the C++ world - think that all classes within a module are friends. It is a language design decision, and a pretty damn good one, IMHO.

Read this section: http://dlang.org/cpptod.html#friends

In short: tightly coupled classes (friends in the C++ world) should be inside the same module.

D is a modular programming language, keep that in mind as this makes it different than C++ or Java.

Comment: Maybe there is a reason to not do that, but that's not my question. My question is how (if possible) to do this. The reasoning is left to the programmer. And even if you are right, then there still may be case when two, tightly coupled classess, have 2000 lines each. So putting them side by side makes file too big.